# Multithreading in Python: Parallel comparison of objects in an iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, pool

I would like to parallelize a script that returns a list of non-equivalent objects. (In practice, "objects" are graphs and I am looking for sets of non-isomorphic graphs in very large sets of graphs.)

Here is some pseudo code:

```
from itertools import combinations
from multiprocessing import Pool

p = Pool(number_of_threads)

def find_nonequivalent_objects(n,m):
    list_of_objects = []
    # LOOP 1: many billions of combinations
    for c in combinations(n,m): 
        new_obj  = generate_object_from_combination(c)
        if not len(list_of_objects)==0:
            compare_to_new_obj = lambda old_obj: check_equivalence(new_obj, 
                                                                   old_obj)
            # MAP 1: a few hundred comparisons
            if not np.any(map(compare_to_new_obj, list_of_objects)):
                list_of_objects = list_of_objects + [new_obj]
        else:
            list_of_objects = [new_obj]

    # return a list of a few hundred objects
    return list_of_objects
```

I first tried to use `p.map` for MAP 1 (replacing the lambda function with `functools.partial`), but the added overhead overcompensated for the speed-up, so the overall runtime increased. It seems that the better approach would be split LOOP 1 into chunks. This would require something like this:

```
list_of_lists_of_objects = pool.map(LOOP1_function, combinations(n,m))

# compare list_of_objects from different chunks
for i in range(1, number_of_threads):
    for new_obj in list_of_lists_of_objects[i]:
        compare_to_new_obj = lambda old_obj: check_equivalence(new_obj, old_obj)
        if not np.any(map(compare_to_new_obj, list_of_lists_of_objects[0])):
            list_of_lists_of_objects[0] = list_of_lists_of_objects[0] + [new_obj]

list_of_objects = list_of_lists_of_objects[0]
```

This leads me to two problems:

1. As far as I understand, using `p.map` on LOOP 1 means that I am asking the machine to create a list of `itertools.combinations(n,m)`. That would lead to memory problems.
2. Every worker or chunk needs to have its own `list_of_objects`. How can I make this happen?

Comment: You may want to take a look at map-reduce patterns, this seems to match exactly what you want to do.

Comment: **Before any high-level syntax "idea" gets coded, do try to rather understand, how the toys work :** - python is an interpreted language - interpretation has a principally limited knowledge of code-execution "collisions", "race-state(s)" and since ever, python used GIL-lock ( **G**lobal-**I**nterpreter-**L**ock ) to avoid any form of concurrent events ( yes, you read it right - it **AVOIDS** anything to happen in a "*just*"-**`[CONCURRENT]` the less in a true-`[PARALLEL]`** fashion - so all the code is executed as a pure-`[SERIAL]` ! code-execution, on several "streams-of-work" step after step

Comment: This said, only some latency-masking makes sense to be organised using threading backend of the `multiprocessing` module ( like fetching some "far" data across the internet-latency distance ). This is a by-design-feature of the python interpreter, which Guido van Rossum acknowledged to be a rather forever respected design, not a seasonal feature innovated in any near future. Escapes from this property are available, often via tensor-efficient ops with vectorised tricks ( high-proximity (dense DATA ) small [SPACE] of data-layout, where caches may help ) or using LLVM-jit/compiled py-extensions

Comment: None of these methods likes to work with smart, weakly-typed and polymorphic-by-nature python objects (list,dict,etc).So, if performance is the must, be careful on using any higher-level objects, as using 'em will almost always limit your choice of performance motivated moves into compiled-python-extension. Last but not least, unless you are sure to have a matching technology, the "outer" syntax-wrapper is the least important. The performance boost grows from understanding all the add-on costs - **not to pay way more than you ever receive back** - https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3